# How to run Ruby Test in Sublime Text with using Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vagrant, sublimetext, ruby-test

On Windows I'm install RubyTest Plugging for SublimeText3.

I'm runing Vagrant with CentOS6.5 where is my Rails4 project with configured rspec.

How I can start RubyTest Plugging in SublimeText3 which run rspec tests through vagrant on virtual CentOS but not on Windows?

I'm set:

```
{
  "ignored_directories": [".git", "vendor", "tmp"],
  "run_rspec_command": "vagrant ssh --command \"'cd /vagrant/sites/sample_app && rspec spec'\""
}
```

It works!

But how to set for run:

1) only active test file?

2) only active line in test file?

PS It works only in SublimeText2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success with a custom RubyTest command.  Crafting that command depends on your individual setup, but my configuration looks like the following:

```
{
  "ignored_directories": [ ".git", "tmp" ],
  "run_rspec_command": "cd $DIR_WITH_VAGRANTFILE && vagrant ssh --command \"cd /vagrant/`echo {relative_path} | sed 's/\\/spec.*$//'` && bundle exec rspec `echo {relative_path} | sed 's,^[^/]*.*/spec,spec,'`\"",
  "run_single_rspec_command": "cd DIR_WITH_VAGRANTFILE && vagrant ssh --command \"cd /vagrant/`echo {relative_path} | sed 's/\\/spec.*$//'` && bundle exec rspec `echo {relative_path} | sed 's,^[^/]*.*/spec,spec,'` -l{line_number}\"",
}
```

These commands makes a few assumptions.

1. You have an environment variable called `$DIR_WITH_VAGRANTFILE` that has the path to the directory which contains your Vagrantfile
2. That directory is mounted at /vagrant in your VM
3. There are several rails apps under that directory, e.g. /vagrant/rails_app_1, /vagrant/rails_app_2

The command works by extracting the full folder path from the relative_file variable, and remotely executing `bundle exec rspec` on the filename.

If you hvae a simpler setup with the rails app being directly within /vagrant, then you should be able to get away with something like the following:

```
{
  "ignored_directories": [ ".git", "tmp" ],
  "run_rspec_command": "cd $DIR_WITH_VAGRANTFILE && vagrant ssh --command \"cd /vagrant && bundle exec rspec {relative_path}\"",
  "run_single_rspec_command": "cd DIR_WITH_VAGRANTFILE && vagrant ssh --command \"cd /vagrant && bundle exec rspec {relative_path} -l{line_number}\"",
}
```

Note: If you have multiple rails apps in different setups and different locations, you'll have to change this setup for each configuration.